# Chinese Text Mining

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

I used Chinese word segment to do Text Mining. And I changed data type to dataframe had comma and double quotation mark. So the wordcloud is strange. Like this:
[image: strange wordcloud]

My syntax as below:
    inspect(d.corpus)

[image: inspect(d.corpus) pic]

```
d.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(as.character(d.corpus))))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(d.corpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(2, Inf)))
m1 <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m1), decreasing = TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)
wordcloud(d$word, d$freq, min.freq = 5, random.order = F, ordered.colors = F, 
    colors = rainbow(length(row.names(m1))))
```

How can I modify data?

I tried to split the syntax:

```
d.corpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(data.frame(as.character(d.corpus)))).
```

Why `as.character(d.corpus)` has 3rows?

```
test1 <- as.character(d.corpus)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it that I used for loop edit names(v) data.

```
for (i in 1:length(names(v)))
{
    names(v)[i] <- gsub('[\",]','',names(v)[i])
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Hhe.png)